# Mute specific application in Windows without nircmd

Tags: audio, mute, nircmd

One of my games will not respond to the usual nircmd command to mute it:

```
nircmd snircmd muteappvolume Cyberpunk2077.exe 1
```

I suspect it may not be working as it may be one of those applications that spawns another that controls the audio:

[image]

I have also tried:

```
nircmd snircmd muteappvolume "Cyberpunk 2077 (C) 2020 by CD Projekt RED" 1
nircmd snircmd muteappvolume "Cyberpunk 2077 (C) 2020 by CD Projekt" 1
nircmd snircmd muteappvolume "Cyberpunk 2077 (C) 2020 by CD" 1
nircmd snircmd muteappvolume "Cyberpunk 2077 (C) 2020 by" 1
nircmd snircmd muteappvolume "Cyberpunk 2077 (C) 2020" 1
nircmd snircmd muteappvolume "Cyberpunk 2077 (C)" 1
nircmd snircmd muteappvolume "Cyberpunk 2077" 1
nircmd snircmd muteappvolume "Cyberpunk" 1
```

None of these worked either.
This command works fine with other applications, so I know I have used the right commands, and that nircmd is installed.

Since this fails, and nircmd is deprecated, I am looking for another way via script (`.bat` or `.AHK`) to mute my game. How can I achieve this in Windows 10?

Comment: Check the executable that needs to be muted; it might *not* be Cyberpunk2077.exe. Look in Task Manager to see if Cyberpunk spawns other processes; it might be one of *those* processes controls sound volume.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I thought of this too, but I wasn't sure what to with what I was looking at (I've added a photo in the original post to see what I mean). If it is indeed a secondary application that is controlling the audio, is it still possible to access it via nircmd?

Comment: Why not try? See what starts with, or immediately after Cyberpunk2077.exe in Task Manager's **Details** tab, and substitute one at a time for *Cyberpunk2077.exe*. Let me know here if one works, and I'll make it an answer. Or you could do so.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks again, but I am not sure what you are suggesting as a course of action. When you say 'substitute' do you mean to replace "Cyberpunk2077.exe" with "Cyberpunk 2077 (C) 2020 by CD Projekt RED" ? If so do I do it with quotes? Sorry I looked at the documentation for this and all the example have ".exe" In the details tab there is only "Cyberpunk2077.exe"

Comment: in `nircmd snircmd muteappvolume Cyberpunk2077.exe 1`

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I've added a list of variations of the `nircmd` commands to the original post to show what hasn't worked. Was this what you were suggesting to try?

Comment: 1. Find the **name** of the other process that is started by Cyberpunk2077.exe. 2. Substitute the **name of that process** for Cyberpunk2077.exe.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik sorry I dont see any other processes. Its just cyberpunk2077.exe and that is not working to be muted.

Comment: Have you tried running that as an admin? It'd seem it helped other people. Also, there's AutoHotKey

Comment: @Netan wow that actually worked. Please feel free to post that in an answer and I will award you the bounty.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Awesome! Glad it helped. I'll write an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run nircmd as an Administrator ( or, from a CMD that's been opened as admin )

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue immediately.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. haha once again, it was Microsoft's fault

Answer (score 1):

You could still try :

```
nircmd setappvolume Cyberpunk2077.exe 0
```

If this also doesn't work,
many games I have seen can be muted from their Settings.
If Cyberpunk is not one of them, it can still be muted from the
Windows Volume mixer, which is invoked with the command
`sndvol.exe`.

If everything fails, or if you want to be more selective regarding
which part of Cyberpunk to mute, this requires a
[mod from nexusmods.com](https://www.nexusmods.com/cyberpunk2077/mods/).

I have found these two mods (but there are probably others):

- [Mute the sound](https://www.nexusmods.com/cyberpunk2077/mods/1272?tab=files)
- [Quiet Menus](https://www.nexusmods.com/cyberpunk2077/mods/3678)

Comment: Thanks harrymc. While the 'Quiet Menus' achieves my end goal, it is not a sustainable solution as mods often get broken with game updates, or can be incompatible with other mods. I am really hoping to get a Windows script to make this work (as stated in my question), either .bat, AHK, "Powershell etc to get this working. It would be great to understand why `nircmd` isn't doing what it is supposed to.

Comment: What is the process executable when the game is running?

Comment: `Cyberpunk2077.exe`

Comment: Have you tried `nircmd setappvolume Cyberpunk2077.exe 0` ?

Comment: `nircmd setappvolume Cyberpunk2077.exe` 0 did not work.

Comment: It starts to look strange. Can the Volume mixer mute this app (and only it letting others use audio)?

Answer (score 1):

There's a freeware ["SoundVolumeView" from Nirsoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html) which has extensive [command line tools](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_command_line.html) and is said to be compatible up to Windows 11.

So, once installed, you can do something like:

```
svcl.exe /Mute "Cyberpunk2077.exe"
```

or:

```
svcl.exe /SetVolume "Cyberpunk2077.exe" 0
```

Comment: Would this run automatically like nircmd does or would I have to start the process first?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid If you download the command line tool from my second link, it runs on the fly - no need to start the process first. The GUI version (first link) on the other hand let's you create desktop shortcuts to execute dedicated tasks (Mute / Unmute / change vol ...)